# Fetch data on button click with custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to load data with a custom hook initially on page load as well as on button click.

On any click, the amount of records should increased by a fixed number.
The problem is, that my hook will cause an infinite loop caused by permanent rerender.
How do I solve those things with custom hooks?

```js
    function useLoadPokemon(increaseTo) {

      const [pokemonState, setPokemonState] = useState([]);
      const [amount, setAmount] = useState(increaseTo);

      const apolloClient = new useApolloClient(getApolloContext());

      useEffect(() => {

        function load() {

          const getPokemon = gql`
            query pokemons($recordCount: Int!){
              pokemons(first:$recordCount) {
                name,
                image
              }
            }
          `;

          apolloClient.query({
            query: getPokemon,
            variables: {
              recordCount: amount,
            },
          })
          .then((pokemon => {
            setPokemonState(pokemon.data.pokemons);
          }));

        }

        load();

      }, [amount])

      const loadPokemon = function(){
        setAmount(amount + amount);
      }

      return [{ pokemonState }, loadPokemon];
    }

    function ShowPokemon() {

      let [{ pokemonState }, loadPokemon] = useLoadPokemon(5);

      // ...

      <input type="button" value="Lade mehr..." onClick={() => { loadPokemon();}}></input>
```

Error Message:
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: can you try passing as second arguments of useEffect : [] instead of [amount] ?

Comment: Has no effect :-(

Comment: Are you sure you have to use `new` in `const apolloClient = new useApolloClient(getApolloContext());`?

Comment: Don't you instantiate Apollo client in every render? should be on useRef instance.

Comment: It‘s just an example I built for me to understand hooks cause I ran into the same problem with my real project. I just want to split my hooks down for a better structure and readability :-)

Comment: Maybe instantiating Apollo every render causing issue